# Quickstart VM Cloudera parcel won't start

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have a problem understanding something with the Cloudera Quickstart VM. Let me try to explain by outlining my steps so far.

1. I want to write something using Kafka to connect to a web service and ingest a data feed.
2. I'm going to use the Cloudera 5.5 quickstart VM as my playground.
3. I need to have CDH installed from parcels to then get Kafka. Via https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Apache-Hadoop-Concepts-and/cloudera-manager-5-4-0-installing-kafka-parcel-fails/td-p/30615
4. I saw a nifty "Migrate to Parcels" icon on the desktop of the Cloudera VM, so I clicked on it and let it finish.
5. I try to start up the cloudera service and now I get all these  below -

   ```
   impala-server: unrecognized service

   impala-catalog: unrecognized service
   sqoop-metastore: unrecognized service
   solr-server: unrecognized service
   oozie: unrecognized service
   impala-state-store: unrecognized service
   hue: unrecognized service
   flume-ng-agent: unrecognized service
   hbase-regionserver: unrecognized service
   sqoop2-server: unrecognized service
   spark-history-server: unrecognized service
   sentry-store: unrecognized service
   hive-server2: unrecognized service
   hive-metastore: unrecognized service
   hbase-thrift: unrecognized service
   hbase-rest: unrecognized service
   hbase-master: unrecognized service
   hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager: unrecognized service
   hadoop-yarn-proxyserver: unrecognized service
   hadoop-yarn-nodemanager: unrecognized service
   hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver: unrecognized service
   hadoop-httpfs: unrecognized service
   hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode: unrecognized service
   hadoop-hdfs-namenode: unrecognized service
   hadoop-hdfs-journalnode: unrecognized service
   hadoop-hdfs-datanode: unrecognized service
   hbase-solr-indexer: unrecognized service
   zookeeper-server: unrecognized service
   [QuickStart] Disabling CDH services on boot...
   error reading information on service impala-server: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service impala-catalog: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service sqoop-metastore: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service solr-server: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service oozie: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service impala-state-store: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hue: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service flume-ng-agent: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hbase-regionserver: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service sqoop2-server: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service spark-history-server: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service sentry-store: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hive-server2: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hive-metastore: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hbase-thrift: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hbase-rest: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hbase-master: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-yarn-proxyserver: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-httpfs: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-hdfs-namenode: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-hdfs-journalnode: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hadoop-hdfs-datanode: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service hbase-solr-indexer: No such file or directory
   error reading information on service zookeeper-server: No such file or directory
   [QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Manager daemons...
   [QuickStart] Waiting for Cloudera Manager API...
   ```

Later on, I obviously dont see the process running when I do a "top" command.  What else should I be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a super easy fix.  I started the cloudera manager service

```
service cloudera-scm-server restart
```

And I started the cloudera agent

```
service cloudera-scm-agent restart
```

went into the Cloudera Manager Home at http://quickstart.cloudera:7180/cmf/home

Then in the status tab I just started each service.  It was all done with the GUI it was easy